# GraphQL skip query result validation

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I have a query in a resolver that grabs 100s of documents from a DB. The service call is mere milliseconds, but it takes 30-60 seconds for GraphQL to go through every document and validate the layout. Is there *any* way for a specific query/resolver to skip this validation? Or am I forced to use REST? I am using Apollo on both sides.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way might be to declare the results as scalar type JSON instead of defining a full structure for the documents. This type is available in the graphql-scalars package.

You could define only high level fields as normal scalars then leave everything else out of your type.

```
type Document {
  id: ID!
  title: String
  publicationDate: Date
  status: String!
  authors: [Author!]!
  details: JSON
}
```